# Central heating component identification

Tags: central-heating, plumbing-fixture

I am just wondering what the brass pot is? It's hot, and attached to the pump, as well as pipes leading downstairs and to some storage tank.

It also sounds as if some small ball bearings are swirling around in it; is this normal?

[image: what's the bras pot?]

Comment: Is this a fired unit, meaning does it have a burner? If so, is the burner unit in the same enclosure as the pictured equipment? If so, please remove combustible storage from that enclosure/room/closet, or at least make sure it is a safe distance from the fired equipment.

Comment: This assembly is in our loft (attic). We have a condenser boiler downstairs which feeds to the pump at the bottom of the picture.

Comment: It may be an air separator-- need a better picture (pull the camera back to show more of the installation).